# Ubuntu spontaneously won't boot, how do I fix it?

Tags: boot, data-recovery

I have a Lenovo G500 laptop running Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

About a month ago, I installed Ubuntu to replace windows 8.1 because my windows os was corrupted and so was the recovery partition(it has something to do with a ton of registry errors). I couldn't afford to get a new windows os so I installed Ubuntu via a bootable usb.

My computer was working fine a few hours ago. I shut down my computer and went home. When I turn it on, it took a long time on the Lenovo logo screen, then it went black. After a few minutes, some white writing appears on screen for a few seconds and then they go away. There is a lot.

```
 Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
 Copyright (R) 1997-2000 Intel corp.

 For Atheros PCIE Ethernet controller v2.1.1.2 (9/23/12)

 Check cable connection!
 PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE rom.
```

It cycles through that and a blank screen

I tried turning it off and on. I tried the boot options menu. I plugged my bootable usb and it booted Ubuntu from that.
I did not set up a recovery partition yet, but if there's a way to get back some of my files that would be wonderful.

I don't know what was different between the time I shut down my computer and now.

Answer (score 0):

The PXE-M0F tells you that it tries booting from LAN, but without success. Maybe look at your BIOS boot order settings and set hdd and/or cd-dvd and/or USB before LAN and other stuff. However this should not be the only reason why it doesn't boot. But do you mean when you boot from the live-cd you could not access the data on the hard disk? Was it detected and just not mounted (run gparted to see hdd/partitioning info)?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my HDD. I think I'm booting from there, or at least I should be.

Comment: But in your question you wrote you could not boot Ubuntu from hdd, but live from usb-stick. So if you still suffer from this problem, please answer my questions so that I can provide you detailed help. How is your boot order in BIOS? Running live-Ubuntu, can you access (mount and access files) or at least see (e.g. in gparted) your hdd?

Comment: It says: EFI network for IPv4 for (20-1A-06-2C-55-12) boot failed. Checking media [fail] EFI network for IPv6 for (20-1A-06-2C-55-12) boot failed. There is a window that says default boot device missing or boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key, then select boot manager to choose a new boot device or to boot recovery media.

Comment: Do you know how to enter your UEFI (replacement of bios) and check/change boot order?

Comment: My boot device priority is internal HDD, USB HDD, SATA ODD (I think that's the dad drive), Network boot.

Comment: Okay, so this is fine (you have a dad-drive? ;D of course I know it's DVD). So would you please live-boot to ubuntu and tell me what partitions you have? (run `gparted` which has a GUI or run `sudo parted`, enter your pw and when `(parted)` appears, enter `print` or `print all` (if you have more than 1 hdd). Post the output. Exit parted by entering `q`)